# Private Contractors or Mercenaries an alternative to Army or Soldiers?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, near-future, military

Do you think in the near future countries should start investing on Private Contractors or Mercenaries rather than investing and wasting money on the army?
What do you think are the pro's for hiring contractors to do the job or fight a war?

Comment: If you're looking to develop this into a storyline or world, there's a large body of historical work comparing and contrasting soldiers and mercenaries.

Comment: Which would you rather have, a loyal patriot bound to you ideologically, or a random person who will aim his weapon where ever requested by the highest bidder?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Frosty. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing answers to specific problems you have with a world you are developing. We [do support open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2253/6986), if phrased properly, but this doesn't appear to be such a question as is. I would recommend taking the [tour] to get a better understanding of the site, then making an [edit] to refine your question; otherwise, this may be put on hold until such clarity is added.

Comment: Also, once corporations finally become more prominent that countries (which is already well underway), their fighting forces will automatically be "private contractors"

Answer (score 2):

Should? No. Could? Probably. Look at Iraq and Afganistan. Already there large groups active.

The pro's are probably a lower level of responsibility on the contracting party. It might also be cheaper. You don't need to support a large standing army. The mercenary company will. And unlike countries in peace time they can move from conflict to conflic. Minimizing downtime on equipment.

But to be a true alternative to a country's military the mercenary groups need to be of a size several orders of magnitude over modern private contracters. Arming a group of men is easy, giving them some armored vehicles isn't to hard either. The problems will be in issueing them drones, long range artillery support, submarines and heavy battletanks.

These things have high costs. Both in construction and maintenance. There very few private organisations in the modern world that have the means to field such an organisation.

ANd you can't forgo these things because without it any nation that held on to their own military would wipe the floor with them. That's not even counting on things like nukes. Nobody will accept a private organisation with a nuclear arsenal. But what is stopping a nation of using them defensively against a private force? They're not nuking anybody so who has the right to interfere?

So it's possible but unlikely given the astronomical cost associate with fielding a modern army and you're still most likely blocked by nukes.

Comment: Also, that historically, mercenaries could not be held accountable and sufficiently powerful groups tend to topple the government hiring them and take over themselves

Comment: Which I think modern nation states are aware of and would oppose them forming.

Comment: The OP wants to disband the army and keep only mercenaries. What would they oppose them with? Laws?

Comment: Other nations would oppose such a force. They don't just appear out of the ether, there will be opposition in a transition period.

Comment: Far more likely that the dismissed soldiers will revolt and overthrow the government.

Comment: Depends how they're dismissed? Are they getting reschooled to other jobs? Hired by the mercenary groups? Retired with full benefits? etc.